filter map objects using javascript
I have a map object with key value pair as shown below
const input = new Map([
    [
      0,
      {
        testErrorSummary: "ServiceC\nV4/\n\tcom.dmv.smp",
        appErrorSummary: '{"handler":null,"sourcetype":null}',
        invocations: [
          { radar: "", testCaseMilestone: "1G05" },
          { radar: "3450", testCaseMilestone: "1G15" },
        ],
      },
    ],
    [
      1,
      {
        testErrorSummary: 'java: \nEx:\n <"()">\n <" "code": "403"">',
        appErrorSummary: '{"handler":null,"sourcetype":null}',
        invocations: [
          { radar: "1532", testCaseMilestone: "1G12" },
          { radar: "1954", testCaseMilestone: "1G24" },
        ],
      },
    ],
    [
      2,
      {
        testErrorSummary: "com.dmv: Timeout while waiting.",
        appErrorSummaryKeyword: 'Cannot invoke "com.dmv.getEcid()"',
        hasRadarHistory: false,
        invocations: [
          { radar: "3444", testCaseMilestone: "1G45" },
          { radar: "", testCaseMilestone: "1G90" },
        ],
      },
    ],
  ]);

I have a search input where i enter the string. Based on this string value, i want to filter this above map object. Suppose user enters "50". So i need to check for properties testErrorSummary, appErrorSummary and radar and return only those mapped objects which matches with user entries.
So in this case, user enters 50, i am expecting the below result because those get matched with radar having 50 in it. So filterFailureInput = 50
Expected output
new Map([
    [
      0,
      {
        testErrorSummary: "ServiceC\nV4/\n\tcom.dmv.smp",
        appErrorSummary: '{"handler":null,"sourcetype":null}',
        invocations: [
          { radar: "", testCaseMilestone: "1G05" },
          { radar: "3450", testCaseMilestone: "1G15" },
        ],
      },
    ],
  ]);

In order to achieve this way of filtering, i am doing the following but i dont get the expected filter results. Can someone let me know where i am going wrong with this.
const searchException = () => {
        return new Map(
          Array.from(input).filter(([key, value]) => {
            const matchInvocations = value.invocations.some(
              (invocation) => {
                (invocation?.radar &&
                  invocation?.radar.includes(filterFailureInput)) ||
                (value?.testErrorSummary?.toLowerCase()
                    .includes(filterFailureInput.toLowerCase())) ||
                (value?.appErrorSummaryKeyword?.toLowerCase()
                    .includes(filterFailureInput.toLowerCase()))
          });
            return matchInvocations;
          })
        );
      };

const expectedOutput = searchException();



No need to guard against undefined invocation.radar with code like this: invocation?.radar && invocation?.radar.includes(...). Just write invocation?.radar?.includes(...).

Your filtering function looks mostly correct, but there're some issues.

you should add the missing return some() callback.
you should add a null-safe check for appErrorSummaryKeyword.

Here's updated code.
const searchException = () => {
  return new Map(
    Array.from(input).filter(([key, value]) => {
      const matchInvocations = value.invocations.some((invocation) => 
        invocation?.radar?.includes(filterFailureInput)
      );

      const matchErrorSummary =
        value?.testErrorSummary?.toLowerCase().includes(filterFailureInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value?.appErrorSummaryKeyword?.toLowerCase()?.includes(filterFailureInput.toLowerCase());

      return matchInvocations || matchErrorSummary;
    })
  );
};


Thanks @Js King- understood what i was doing wrong. thanks for explanation. Can you confirm if your final code is properly formatted in the answer.
